# pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError when trying to send message to remote queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to run [RabbitMQ Python tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) but with sender on virtualbox host machine and receiver and queue on virtualbox guest machine. So I modified mentioned *send.py* code by only replacing **localhost** with **192.168.1.5**. When I run it, i receive following error:

```
...
  File "/home/damian/.virtualenvs/kivy_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 153, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
```

rabbitmq-server seems to be running, because when I stop it *send.py* gives me:

```
...
  File "/home/damian/.virtualenvs/kivy_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 301, in _adapter_connect
    raise exceptions.AMQPConnectionError(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: Connection to 192.168.1.5:5672 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

which makes perfect sense.

How to fix that **ProbableAuthenticationError**?

Host machine is Debian 7 with Python 2.7.3 and pika 0.9.14, guest is Ubuntu 15.04 with rabbitmq-server 3.4.3-2

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you are trying to authenticate using the username and password `guest` remotely. Starting with [RabbitMQ 3.3](https://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt) you need to create a new account to use remotely, and `guest/guest` can only be used locally.

This is taken from the change log [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt).

```
25603 prevent access using the default guest/guest credentials except via localhost since (1.0.0)
```

It's possible to modify the RabbitMQ configuration to allow remote access using the `guest` account, by removing `guest` from loopback_users, but it's recommended to create a new user to follow best practices.

```
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].
```